# MeteorJs mobile-config settings for landscape only?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, meteor, mobile-application

I am developing an app for tablets (android and iOS), I am looking for some kind of settings in mobile-config that disable landscape orientation. I know how to do that on iOS by changing some settings on XCode but is their any setting that can do it for both android and iOS.

This only works for android not iOS device

```
App.setPreference('Orientation', 'landscape');
```

Also is it possible to deploy a meteor app just for ipad, i mean now you if deploy it with below command it make it for any ios device. Can i be specific so that it makes only for ipads

```
meteor deploy your-desired-app-hostname.meteor.com
meteor build ~/build-output-directory \
    --server=your-desired-app-hostname.meteor.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching on the topic i came to conclusion that its an open bug and only way to prevent portrait mode on apple's ipad is by manually editing the settings through XCode.

You can check out but [here](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/263)